# SyntaxError: Unexpected number in JSON at position 107

Tags: json, parsing, solidity

I am trying to learn how to deploy a code on Ropsten network which worked fine on ganache but it keeps throwing an error and I am not able to figure it out. Below is the code

```
const fs = require('fs');
const HDWalletProvider = require("@truffle/hdwallet-provider");

const gitignore = JSON.parse (
    fs.readFileSync('.gitignore').toString().trim()
);

module.exports = {
    networks: {
        ropsten: {
            provider: () => 
                new HDWalletProvider(
                    gitignore.seed,
                    'https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/${gitignore.projectID}'
                ),    
            network_id: 3           
        }
    }
};
```

below are the dependency version

Truffle v5.3.9 (core: 5.3.9)
Node v14.17.0
@truffle/hdwallet-provider: "^1.4.1"

Comment: `.gitignore` usually doesn't contain a JSON. What is the reason behind your code trying to parse it as a JSON? Can you edit the question and share the contents of your `.gitignore`?

Comment: solved by using .env